# Datetrim for datetimes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I would like to create a Datetrim function with arguments datepart, datevalue. It should return a datetime from datevalue (which is a datetime) having every date part smaller than the datepart argument trimmed.

Eg:

`(year,'20180703 11:32:45.333')` should return `20180101 00:00:00.000`

`(month,'20180703 11:32:45.333')` should return `20180701 00:00:00.000`

I suppose the body's code would be a case on datepart with all possible dateadd-datediff combos. The question is, can I have my datepart argument be of the same (unknown to me atm) type of the datepart arguments of dateadd/datediff functions?

Or do I just make it a varchar and manually write the dateparts in the case?

Comment: Trim means remove whitespace or unwanted characters from a string. With datetime, *sometimes* it refers to cutting out the time part (just `cast(field as date)`) You are asking about *rounding* though. You'll find a lot of answers if you search for the correct question

Comment: I have an argument of what I am supposed to trim. If datepart=second, it should trim milliseconds. If datepart=minute, it should trim seconds and milliseonds. All the way up to datepart=year, which should trim months and below. Your solution only works for datepart=day.

Comment: That's because you asked for *trimming* when you actually want *rounding*. If you search for `T-SQL date rounding` you'll find a lot of solutions, all of which end up dealing with `dateadd, datediff`. Other SQL dialects have such functinoality, but not T-SQL

Comment: why are you asking this though? It could be a *bad* idea - applying functions to a *field* means you can't use any indexes on that field and the server will have to scan the entire table. If you wanted to find all entries in a month or year though, a FAR better solution would be to use a [Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) with separate fields for year, month, semester, week etc. You could then join by date and select all records for a specific year, month taking advantage of indexing

Comment: Don't think too much, it's rather a laziness thing. Instead of typing DATEADD(x_datepart,0,DATEDIFF(x_datepart,0,y_datetime)), I want to type DATETRIM(x_datepart,y_datetime). You'd still render your indexes ineffective if you used the former.

Comment: Laziness can cost a *lot* if you end up scanning 100K rows for minutes at a time instead of returning 100 rows in milliseconds. Applying any function to a field means the server can't use the indexes created using the *original* data. That's why you have to be *specific* and explain what you actually want to do if you want a good answer. Are you trying format data for display? Filter data by month? Roll up sums? Join tables of different granularity? In the first case, no indexes are involved anyway, the data is already selected. In all other cases using functions can cost a lot

Comment: The datepart argument can't be parameterized. It's a keyword, not a "value".

Comment: I consider your comment an answer, Zohar

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis you still haven't explained why you want that

Comment: I am not required to. I asked something specific, got my answer, and all are happy.

Comment: True, you are not required to. However it might be in your best interest to do so. This post seems to be an [XYPropblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). As it is asking about the solution instead of about the problem. However, if you will explain why you want to do what you want to do, you might get a better solution  then the one you are currently attempting to write.

Comment: Actually, I have explained exactly what I want to do in my "Don't think too much" comment. As it is, I have no specific cause right now. Have you EVER used dateadd(datediff())? Have you ever seen, or advised, anyone to use it? Well, in all these cases, having a function that does exactly that instead, would have saved you/someone else a few characters' worth of typing. To be honest, since I've seen it around so much that it's usual practice, I would expect/recommend ms to implement it at last (much like the trim instead of ltrim(rtrim()), or the string_agg instead of the usual xml solution).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `dateadd()` with `datediff()` as below

```
declare @dt datetime = '20180703 11:32:45.333',
        @flag  int   = 1

select  dateadd(year,  datediff(year, 0, @dt), 0)  as [Year],
        dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @dt), 0) as [Month],
        case @flag  
        when 1 then dateadd(year, datediff(year, 0, @dt), 0)
        when 2 then dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @dt), 0)
        end
```